# WCF - Message Based Security and SSL Accelerator

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, wcf-wshttpbinding

I'm using a WCF service currently that uses message-based security and is intended to be accessed over HTTP, rather than HTTPS.

This has been tested and works a treat. On deploying to a machine that uses an SSL accelerator I am getting the following error.

*"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://.....svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details".*

**Is there a way to get message level security to work over https or are there known clashes with WCF and SSL accelerators**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No You can not go for both Transport and Message Security mode.However you can try using TransportWithMessageCredential << Credentials are passed with the message and message protection and server authenticaion are provided by the transport layer.>>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is related, but I had a similar problem with some machines that were sat behind an F5/BigIP. Ultimately, though, it turned out to be more related to the local IIS configuration, and WCF not being able to correctly resolve the site for http. It worked for https, though. I never did get to the bottom of it; to get the service working I deployed a custom host-factory that snipped http out of the loop *entirely* - it then worked for https, and *completely* ignored http.